# How to temorary store unique row into html table after by clicking add button?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Sorry for my bad english but I have a select dropdown with salary Head (Basic, PF, HRA etc) and a text field with name amount and a add button. I want to know how temporarily store into html table by clicking add button and after that send to server.
[image]

1. each row in temporary html table should be unique.
2. delete button should be there for delete row.
3. if amount change and add button press again then if row already exists should be updated.

below is form

```
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="control-label col-lg-3">SalaryHead</label>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
  <?php
  $attributes = 'class="form-control input-sm" id="salary_head_list"';
  $options =array(
                    '' => '...Select...'
                 );
foreach($SalaryHeadList as $row){
$options[$row->SalaryHeadId] = $row->SalaryHeadName;
}

echo form_dropdown('salary_head_list',$options, '', $attributes);
?>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group required">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="amount">Amount</label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                                <input  type="text" value="" class="form-control input-sm" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <!-- Buttons -->
                                                            <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
                                                                <button type="button" id="add_salary_head" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Add</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

this is my jquery code :-

```
var salary = {};
$('#add_salary_head').on('click',function(){
    var salary_head_id = $("#salary_head_list").val();
    var salary_head_name = $("#salary_head_list option:selected").text();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    if (salary_head_id == '' || amount == '')
    {
        alert("Please select Salary Head and Amount!");
        return false;
    }

    var newRow = $("<tr salaryHeadID=\"" + salary_head_id  + "\" />")
        .appendTo("#salary_head_table")
        .append("<td>" + salary_head_name + "</td>")
        .append("<td>" + amount + "</td>")
        .append("<td>delete</span></td>");


});
```

Comment: Basically, keep track of your data using JS. When adding or updating entries to the table, check your form data against this JS variable. Then update it on the client-side with every change the user makes.

Since you are already using jquery, use $.post or $.ajax to call your server to add or update via AJAX, then do the update server-side on your database.

Comment: add row is ok but when I tried to add again instead of update the duplicate row inserted

Comment: Then what are you doing with this? `var salary = {};` nothing. Update that when adding like `salary[salary_head_name] = amount`. Then next time when updating the same dropdown, you can check `if (typeof salary[salary_head_name] !== 'undefined')` then just update that value, and change the table row instead of calling `$.append()`

Comment: may you write code for this

Comment: no. sorry. Stackoverflow is not made for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this.

```
var newRow = "<tr salaryHeadID=\"" + salary_head_id  + "\" >"
+ "<td>" + salary_head_name + "</td>"
+ "<td>" + amount + "</td>"
+ "<td>delete</td></tr>";

if ($('tr[salaryHeadID='+ salary_head_id +']').length) {
    $('tr[salaryHeadID='+ salary_head_id +']').replaceWith(newRow);
} else {
    $("#salary_head_table").append(newRow);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but nothing happen still insert duplicate row

Comment: i have update the code try it again it works for me i have tested it first

Comment: thanks it works. may you plz give me the idea how I can get data from that table to store into database

Comment: you can save data in an array or object.